# Groth-Sahai proofs and hardness assumptions

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I am learning Groth-Sahai NIZK proof system for Bilinear groups. While going through the literature, I am getting confused on how the proof system is related to Subspace Decision, SXDH or DLIN assumptions. In the proof system, what I understood is to prove the ownership of solution of a set of equations, e.g. Quadratic/Pairing Product etc. Then how does it relate to various hardness assumptions?

Comment: They show that violating the zero-knowledge property is at least as hard as $\hspace{1.67 in}$ violating those hardness assumptions. $\:$

Comment: My understanding is that being able to distinguish between instances of Subspace Decision, SXDH or DLIN assumptions with non-negligible probability corresponds to be able to distinguish between Hiding and Binding keys. But, what does it get translated to further?

Comment: Real executions use Binding keys and the Simulator uses Hiding keys. $\;$

Comment: [GS08] says, "An NP-reduction of even very simple statements like these gives us big circuits containing thousands of gates and the corresponding NIZK proofs become very large".

How does a statement can be reduced to an NP language and be translated to circuits using gates?

Comment: http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/4105-10/CIRCUITSATisNPhard.pdf $\;$

Comment: Groth-Sahai is more of a "template" that you can implement for different groups and assumptions. DLIN, SXDH and subgroup decision are three example implementations given in the original paper.